# Calculating coordinates of median point of polyline using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, geometry, coordinates

I have a shapefile with some polylines. For each one of these polylines I'd like to calculate the median of the polyline (i.e. the point that's equidistant from each end) and then, calculate its coordinates.

The only tools I've found regarding this matter are Mean Center and Median Center. However, this is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In ArcMap you can use the tool:

**Toolboxes \ Data Management Tools \ Features \ Feature To Point**

With the option inside checked.